# python - having problems with sending an image trough socket

Tags: python, sockets, stream, buffer, screenshot

I am new to python and I am trying to make a script that sends/streams a screenshot of my laptop trough socket. If I run these two scripts it works, but after few seconds (I think this is what happens: the client gets overloaded with information), it gives me "pickle data was truncated" error. The tutorial I have been following was only for sending a string message and using a buffer, but the problem is that I'm using a `numpy` array that's pickled and if I buffer it, it will write the second image to the first and give another pickle data truncated error and I don't know what to do.

Any help is appreciated.

server:

```
import numpy as np
import socket
import pickle
import time
import mss
import cv2
import sys

s = socket.socket()
shost = socket.gethostname()
host = socket.gethostbyname(shost) 
port = 8080
s.bind((host,port))
s.listen(5)
print(host)
print("Waiting for any incoming connections ... ")
conn, addr = s.accept()
print(addr, "Has connected to the server")

with mss.mss() as sct: #if i want it to be a different size
    monitor = {"top": 0, "left": 0, "width": 1720, "height": 720}


while True:
    img =  np.array(sct.grab(sct.monitors[1]))
    pack = pickle.dumps(img)
    conn.send(pack)
    print(sys.getsizeof(pack))
```

client:

```
import socket
import numpy as np
import cv2
import pickle
import time


s = socket.socket()
host = input(str("Please enter the host address of the sender : "))
port = 8080
s.connect((host,port))
print("Connected ... ")

while True:
    pack = s.recv(4196540)        
    frame = pickle.loads(pack)
    cv2.imshow("Screen", frame)
    pack = ' '
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: "recv" returns **at most** the number of bytes given as argument but it may return less and you have to collect the data from multiple calls until you got all.

Comment: @MichaelButscher sorry i dont really understand, soo do i need to recv in multiple times or do i need to send the image separated into parts ?

Comment: "recv" must be called multiple times. You must also change its size parameter accordingly or you may receive data belonging to the next image.

Answer (score 0):

[`socket.recv()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recv) while looking similar does not behave the same way as [`.read()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.RawIOBase.read) if a file like object. "Raw" socket programming also does not do a lot of the housekeeping for you and it's up to your code to deal with it.

A stream socket (`SOCK_STREAM` type which is the one opened by default using [`socket.socket()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket) is just that, a stream of bytes and it's essentially agnostic of the content you're passing through it. To make matters more complicated, as mentioned by [Michael Butscher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/987358/michael-butscher) in the comments (and this is where similarity with `read()` may be confusing), its first argument `bufsize` does not say how much data you will receive, it only limits the maximal amount you ready to receive at once. It basically says, I got buffer of this size, give me what you can up to that size.

If you know how much data you are to receive for any given image in your case (and since they fixed size screenshots I guess you may be in luck), you need to keep repeating `recv()` calls until you got a complete image, then perform your actions on it and move on to the next one.

That means you can replace:

```
pack = s.recv(4196540)
```

With something like:

```
item_size = 4196540
pack = b''
while len(pack) < item_size:
    remains = item_size - len(pack)
    bufsize = 4096 if remains > 4096 else remains
    pack += s.recv(bufsize)
```

There are more ways to deal with it, but this essentially runs `recv` until `pack` contains `4196540` bytes of data (one pickled image presumably) and then you can go on to process it.

Otherwise you'd have to employ other technique: you can for instance define your own protocol where first `n` bytes is the size of file that follows and then you know how much data to be expecting for next item to come. Or open new connection for each item (`recv()` on a socket whose other side has been closed does not block and yields `b''`).

BTW that last comment also means, that after last image was sent, the server could do `conn.close()` and bow out (or listen for new incoming connections) and we could make one more change in the snippet above, namely instead of:

```
pack += s.recv(bufsize)
```

say:

```
buf = s.recv(bufsize)
if not buf:
    s.close()
    break  # end the "while True" loop
pack += buf
```

to also stop receiving on the client side.

Also one note regarding the tutorial you've mentioned. In trivial cases... such as sending short string messages, while you should not rely on it, you often get lucky and `recv` all of your expected data in one chunk.